# Why does SU(2) have representations of any positive integer dimensions?

Tags: group-theory, physics

Shouldn't SU(2) be 2*2 unitary matrix of det = 1, so it only has 2 dimensions.
What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: A representation is just a group homomorphism $SU(2) \to GL(n, \mathbb C)$ for some $n$. This $n$ can be as large as you want.

Comment: Find any (finite dimensional) vector space $V$ on which SU(2) acts, then it is a representation of $SU(2)$. Space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ is an $n+1$ dimensional vector space. It is easy to define, in an explicit way, an action of $SU(2)$ on this space.